# What means `PhantomData<T>` in a pallet?

Tags: pallet, frame

I see that some pallets wrap phantom data:

```
pub struct Pallet<T>(PhantomData<T>);
```

and others not:

```
pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
```

Why is it there?
Do I need this in my pallet as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#[pallet::pallet]` macro simply replaced the `_` in the definition above to `PhantomData<T>`.

See the notes here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/pallet_struct.rs

```
/// * Add derive trait on Pallet
/// * Implement GetStorageVersion on Pallet
/// * Implement OnGenesis on Pallet
/// * Implement `fn error_metadata` on Pallet
/// * declare Module type alias for construct_runtime
--> /// * replace the first field type of `struct Pallet` with `PhantomData` if it is `_`
/// * implementation of `PalletInfoAccess` information
/// * implementation of `StorageInfoTrait` on Pallet
```

and the code:

```
// If the first field type is `_` then we replace with `PhantomData`
if let Some(field) = pallet_item.fields.iter_mut().next() {
    if field.ty == syn::parse_quote!(_) {
        field.ty = syn::parse_quote!(
            #frame_support::sp_std::marker::PhantomData<(#type_use_gen)>
        );
    }
}
```

So it is the same thing, and just a friendly "type inference magic" done for the pallet developer.

Answer (score 5):

A phantom type parameter is simply a type parameter which is never used. In Rust, this often causes the compiler to complain, and the solution is to add a “dummy” use by way of PhantomData.

Adding a PhantomData field to your type tells the compiler that your type acts as though it stores a value of type T, even though it doesn’t really. This information is used when computing certain safety properties.

- Rustnomicon: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html
- Substrate docs: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.PhantomData.html

Comment: So basically just to make the compiler happy? No change in the pallet execution logic?

Comment: There is a bit more about it, I think. The example in the substrate docs about lifetime is great, explaining how you can use PhantomData to define that a certain struct should not outlive `'a` for that concrete example.
But I am not aware if this affects the execution of this logic. I would guess it does not.